# Unity Alpha Diffuse Mask Shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, alpha

I am working in Unity, with the latest version of Unity 5.2.2 and I am asking, if it is possible to create an alpha mask shader that can fade the mask. Right now I have this shader

```
Shader "MaskedTexture"
{
   Properties
   {
      _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
      _Mask ("Culling Mask", 2D) = "white" {}
      _Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range (0,1)) = 0.1
   }
  SubShader
  {
      Tags {"Queue"="Transparent"}
      Lighting Off
      ZWrite Off
      Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
      AlphaTest GEqual [_Cutoff]
  Pass
  {
     SetTexture [_Mask] {combine texture}
     SetTexture [_MainTex] {combine texture, previous}
  }
  }
}
```

[image]

I need to add a color propertie or something? What I want is to just fade this object away so that it is not visible anymore. I can't just disable it, it actually has to fade smoothly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
Shader "MaskTexture"
{
   Properties
   {
     _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
     _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Transparency (A)", 2D) = "" { }
      _Mask ("Culling Mask", 2D) = "white" {}
   }
   SubShader
   {
      Tags { "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue" = "Transparent" }
      Lighting Off
      ZWrite Off
      Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
      AlphaTest GEqual [_Cutoff]
      Pass
      {

        SetTexture [_Mask] {combine texture}

        SetTexture [_MainTex] { combine texture, previous }

        SetTexture [_MainTex] {
            constantColor [_Color]
            combine previous * constant
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don`t know the way you are doing the masking, but usualy I would use a pixelshader for that. 
I found this blogpost and I think it is helpful for you.
http://bensilvis.com/unity3d-unlit-alpha-mask-shader/

I used the code and added a extra value for alpha  to adjust the amount of masking.

```
// - no lightmap support
// - no per-material color

Shader "AlphaMask" {
Properties {
_alphaValue ("Alpha Value", Range (0, 1)) = 1
_MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
_AlphaTex ("Alpha mask (R)", 2D) = "white" {}

}

SubShader {
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
LOD 100

ZWrite Off
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

Pass {  
    CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata_t {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _AlphaTex;
        float _alphaValue;

        float4 _MainTex_ST;

        v2f vert (appdata_t v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
            fixed4 col2 = tex2D(_AlphaTex, i.texcoord);

            //Uncomment for only alpha of mask
            //float alpha = col2.r+_alphaValue;
            //return fixed4(col.r, col.g, col.b,alpha);
             return fixed4(col.r, col.g, col.b,_alphaValue);
        }
    ENDCG
}
}
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Hi thank you, but this is not what I am looking for, I don't want to set the alpha of only the mask, I want to set the alpha of both at the same time

Comment: then replace those lines at the end from:

float alpha = col2.r+_alphaValue;   delete this line
return fixed4(col.r, col.g, col.b,alpha); change this lineto 


           return fixed4(col.r, col.g, col.b,_alphaValue);